# Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.String` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)

Tags: java, deserialization, jackson-databind

I have one class called `Configurations`

```
public class Configurations {

private List<Configuration> configurations; 
}

public class Configuration {
    private String configurationClass;
    private ConfigurationProperties configurationProperties;
}

public class ConfigurationProperties {
    private String propertiesClass;
    private String propertiesJson;
}

public class SchoolProperties {
    @JsonProperty("serviceName")
    String serviceName;

    @JsonProperty("operationName")
    String operationName;

    @JsonProperty("latency")
    Long latency;

    @JsonProperty("permittedTransactionsPerSecond")
    int permittedTransactionsPerSecond;

    Class<? extends Throwable>[] possibleExceptions;
}
```

there is one more class called ConfigurationProperties like below :-

Now i'm passing a Json-Object like below:-

```
  input =   "{
        "configurations": [{
            "configurationClass": "src.myProject.OperationHandler",
            "configurationProperties": {
                "propertiesClass": "src.myProjects.schoolProperties",
                "propertiesJson": {
                    "serviceName": "SchoolAdministerService",
                    "operationName": "handleAdmission",
                    "latency": "25",
                    "permittedTransactionsPerSecond": "50",
                    "possibleExceptions": ["java.io.IOException", "java.net.SocketException", "java.net.SocketTimeoutException"]
                }
            }
        }]
    }";

  type = "Configurations.class";
```

When i'm trying to deserialize it with below way, it's getting failed:-

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

objectMapper.readValue(input, type);
```

After running this de-serialization logic, this is getting failed with below-error:-

```
    Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.String` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
at [Source: (String)"{"configurations":[{"configurationClass":"src.myProject.OperationHandler","configurationProperties":{"propertiesClass":"src.myProjects.schoolProperties","propertiesJson":{
                "serviceName": "SchoolAdministerService",
                "operationName": "handleAdmission",
                "latency": "25",
                "permittedTransactionsPerSecond": "50",
                "possibleExceptions": ["java.io.IOException", "java.net.SocketException", "java.net.SocketTimeoutException"]
            } (through reference chain: Configurations["configurations"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->Configuration["configurationProperties"]->ConfigurationProperties["propertiesJson"])
```

I think the issue is because it's trying to capture propertiesJson as String, but this is not given as string, this is a object. Can someone help, how we should de-serialize it.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You are right about the library not being able to deserialize object into String. You could solve the issue in the following ways:

- If you expect an arbitrary object in `propertiesJson` property you
  could make it of type `Map<String, Object>` in your
  `ConfigurationProperties` class.
- If `propertiesJson` can be of any type(like number, string, array,
  object) you could make it of type `Object`. In such case
  `ObjectMapper` would deserialize the value into an object of the json
  type's respective counterpart in Java.